# How can I optimize this haskell function

Tags: haskell, optimization

I need to find the closest color in a palette `ps` to a given color `p`. How do I make the function `nearestColor` as fast as possible, without changing the type of
`Pixel8` or `PixelRGB8`. So far I have tried inlining.

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V

type Pixel8 = Word8    

data PixelRGB8 = PixelRGB8 {-# UNPACK #-} !Pixel8 -- Red
                           {-# UNPACK #-} !Pixel8 -- Green
                           {-# UNPACK #-} !Pixel8 -- Blue
           deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

nearestColor :: PixelRGB8 -> Vector PixelRGB8 -> PixelRGB8
nearestColor p ps = snd $ V.minimumBy comp ds
  where
    ds = V.map (\px -> (dist2Px px p, px)) ps
    comp a b = fst a `compare` fst b

dist2Px :: PixelRGB8 -> PixelRGB8 -> Int
dist2Px (PixelRGB8 r1 g1 b1) (PixelRGB8 r2 g2 b2) = dr*dr + dg*dg + db*db
  where
    (dr, dg, db) =
      ( fromIntegral r1 - fromIntegral r2
      , fromIntegral g1 - fromIntegral g2
      , fromIntegral b1 - fromIntegral b2 )
```

Comment: Can we see the code for `dist2Px`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You could try profiling it, you could inline those local functions `ds` and `comp`, you could compile to core and search for bottlenecks, then compile to assembly and make sure that you have tight loops.

Comment: I suspect building a vector with only the distances, and using `minIndex` to lookup the result in the original vector could be faster: `ps ! V.minIndex (V.map (\px -> dist2Px px p) ps)`

Comment: @Tamil - doesn't speed things up, but it's cleaner, thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to optimise: time for a single function call, or average for a whole lot of calls for different colours but the same palette?

Comment: I want to optimize for the average of a lot of calls for different colors but the same palette

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use a single palette and request different colours, I'd first flip your signature:

```
type Palette = V.Vector PixelRGB8
nearestColor :: Palette -> PixelRGB8 -> PixelRGB8
```

That facilitates partial application, and allows the palette configuration to be memoised.

Next, you want to do that: re-store the palette in a data structure suitable for fast lookup. Since you're basically interested in Euclidean distance in ℝ<sup>3</sup> (BTW not really ideal for colour comparison), this is a very common problem. A classic structure is the *k*-d tree, which [has long been used for such a nearest-neighbour search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Nearest_neighbour_search). There's sure enough [a Haskell library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/KdTree-0.2.1/docs/Data-Trees-KdTree.html) available, which quite a convenient interface for you:

```
import qualified Data.Trees.KdTree a s KD

instance KD.Point PixelRGB where
  dimension _ = 3
  coord 0 (PixelRGB r _ _) = fromIntegral r
  coord 1 (PixelRGB _ g _) = fromIntegral g
  coord 2 (PixelRGB _ _ b) = fromIntegral b
  dist2 = fromIntegral . dist2Px
```

Then we can transform a palette into such a tree:

```
type FastPalette = KD.KdTree PixelRGB8
accelPalette :: Palette -> FastPalette
accelPalette = KD.fromList . V.toList
```

And finally just use the library-provided next neighbour search:

```
nearestColor palette = fromJust . KD.nearestNeighbor fpal
 where fpal = accelPalette palette
```

Comment: I up voted, because this is a great answer. Unfortunately, I'm restricted to only use packages in the Haskell Platform. btw there are some types coord1 ... = fromIntegral g, etc

Comment: Well, you can of course also re-implement the _k_-d tree yourself, it's not that difficult.